# msSiteModeActivate does not seem to work

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-9

Hi I'm working on some IE9 task bar integration but I cant seem to get `msSiteModeActivate()` to work.

My code:

```
setTimeout("tvOverlay()", 30000);
setTimeout("tvActivate()", 35000);

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function tvActivate() {
                try {
                    if (window.external.msIsSiteMode()) {
                        window.external.msSiteModeActivate();                    
                    }
                    else { }
                }
                catch (e) { }
            }
            function tvOverlay() {
                try {
                    if (window.external.msIsSiteMode()) {
                        window.external.msSiteModeSetIconOverlay('/tvoverlaygul.ico', 'TV Overlay');
                    }
                    else { }
                }
                catch (e) { }
            }            
        </script>
```

The `tvOverlay()` works fine but the icon never flashes when `tvActivate()` is called

Comment: did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? As an example. The following script redirects to a start page if the current window is already running as a pinned site. The `try/catch` statement allows the script to recover gracefully if the call is not supported by the browser.

Also see this for more info on `msSiteModeActivate`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff976297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

UPDATE: New documentation:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/01/17/working-with-pinned-sites.aspx

```
function testSiteMode()
{
    try {
        if (window.external.msIsSiteMode()) {
            location.href = startPage;
        }
    }
    catch(ex) {
        alert("Site Mode is not supported.");
        return;
    }
}
window.onload = testSiteMode;
```